# Put an image down a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xml

I want to put my image (id:imgAbout) at the bottom of the page.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#9AB89C"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Vue.MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvDevice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <ImageButton
        android:onClick="aboutPage"
        android:id="@+id/imgAbout"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_about"
        android:background="#9AB89C"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I do not see how to do that in a LinearLayout.should I use a RelativeLayout?

Comment: Can you show me how exactly do you want it to look like so,I can quickly do it?

Comment: i want this https://screenpresso.com/=bQThf

Comment: I have added an answer you can take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set recycler view's width and height to this

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 2):

-First of all never use static height or width for a Component (RecyclerView). Use wrap content or match parent..
-Second if you will use static height or width, using dp is a better choice than sp (sp is preferable for textSize)..

If you prefer LinearLayout you can use this one. (%90 percentage of screen will be RecyclerView and %10 percentage of screen will be Button, vertically)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#9AB89C"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvDevice"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="9" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgAbout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#9AB89C"
    android:onClick="aboutPage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And if you prefer RelativeLayout use this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#9AB89C">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/rvDevice"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imgAbout"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgAbout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#9AB89C"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="aboutPage" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Both will do what you want..

Answer (score 1):

Use a RelativeLayout something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#9AB89C"
tools:context=".Vue.MainActivity">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvDevice"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
<ImageButton
    android:onClick="aboutPage"
    android:id="@+id/imgAbout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_about"
    android:background="#9AB89C"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

FYI height margin and padding should be assigned in dp where as text size should be in sp